# JavaFX How to resize an Pane children

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to make a software with multiple pane. The architecture was base on a main page with BorderPane. On the bottom a menu bar to navigate between the panels, and in the center of the BorderPane an Pane.
When I click for the dashboard button, I call the dashboardPane.fxml but it's impossible to set the good size of the pane unless if I hardcode the size on the fxml.

I have see lot of exemple with AnchorPane and static size of screen but it's not match with my project. I want to make a responsive software so I don't want to hardcode the size of each pane...

I think my idea is possible but I don't know where is my mistake. Is there any suggestion how to change and rezise pane?

EDIT : I have read the comments of jewelsea so I put some more informations.

The pictures of the software and what I got is just below. It's possible to see in color the children pane and I don't understand how is it possible to change this size. I have also tried to use this line `fxml.resize(x,y);` without results...

[Dashboard Pane](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NcWhv.png)

[Components Pane](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8nRbN.png)

Here is my code :

**mainPageNavigation.java**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

public class mainPageNavigation extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(mainPageNavigation.class.getResource("mainPage.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(fxmlLoader.load(), 800, 500);
        stage.setTitle("CompoDB");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

**mainPageController.java**

```
package DisplayPack;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;

import java.io.IOException;

public class mainPageController {

    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //Initialize mainPage
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    @FXML
    private Pane mainPane;
    private double x, y;


    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //Upper bar control
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    @FXML
    private void addcomponent(MouseEvent event)        {

    }

    @FXML
    private void addstock(MouseEvent event)        {

    }

    @FXML
    private void removestock(MouseEvent event)        {

    }


    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //Bottom bar control
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    @FXML
    private void dashboardClick(ActionEvent actionEvent) throws IOException {
        x = mainPane.getHeight();
        y = mainPane.getWidth();
        System.out.println(x);
        System.out.println(y);
        Parent fxml = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("dashboardPane.fxml"));
        fxml.prefHeight(x);
        fxml.prefWidth(y);
        mainPane.getChildren().setAll(fxml);
    }

    @FXML
    private void componentsClick(javafx.event.ActionEvent actionEvent) throws IOException {
        x = mainPane.getScaleX();
        y = mainPane.getScaleY();
        System.out.println(x);
        System.out.println(y);
        Parent fxml = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("componentsPane.fxml"));
        mainPane.getChildren().removeAll();
        fxml.setScaleX(x);
        fxml.setScaleY(y);
        mainPane.getChildren().setAll(fxml);
    }

    @FXML
    private void projectsClick()     {
    }

    @FXML
    private void toolsClick()        {
    }
}
```

**mainPage.fxml**

```
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ButtonBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.effect.Blend?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>

<BorderPane fx:id="mainBorderPane" prefHeight="900.0" prefWidth="1306.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/18" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="DisplayPack.mainPageController">
    <bottom>
        <ButtonBar fx:id="tool_bar" nodeOrientation="LEFT_TO_RIGHT" prefHeight="50.0" styleClass="tool_bar" stylesheets="@../CSS/MainDarkTheme.css" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
            <buttons>
                <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#dashboardClick" prefHeight="50.0" text="Dashboard">
                    <graphic>
                        <ImageView fitHeight="40.0" fitWidth="75.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                            <image>
                                <Image url="@../IconsPack/white-dashboard-100.png" />
                            </image>
                        </ImageView>
                    </graphic>
                </Button>
                <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#componentsClick" prefHeight="50.0" text="Components">
                    <graphic>
                        <ImageView fitHeight="40.0" fitWidth="75.0" onMouseClicked="#componentsClick" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                            <image>
                                <Image url="@../IconsPack/white-processor-100.png" />
                            </image>
                        </ImageView>
                    </graphic>
                </Button>
                <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onMouseClicked="#projectsClick" prefHeight="50.0" text="Projects">
                    <graphic>
                        <ImageView fitHeight="40.0" fitWidth="75.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                            <image>
                                <Image url="@../IconsPack/white-group-of-projects-100.png" />
                            </image>
                        </ImageView>
                    </graphic>
                </Button>
                <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onMouseClicked="#toolsClick" prefHeight="50.0" prefWidth="700.0" stylesheets="@../CSS/MainDarkTheme.css" text="Tools">
                    <graphic>
                        <ImageView fitHeight="40.0" fitWidth="75.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                            <image>
                                <Image url="@../IconsPack/white-tools-100.png" />
                            </image>
                        </ImageView>
                    </graphic>
                </Button>
            </buttons>
            <effect>
                <Blend />
            </effect>
         <BorderPane.margin>
            <Insets />
         </BorderPane.margin>
        </ButtonBar>
    </bottom>
    <top>
        <HBox prefHeight="33.0" prefWidth="1306.0" styleClass="background" stylesheets="@../CSS/MainDarkTheme.css" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
            <children>
                <ImageView fitHeight="65.0" fitWidth="71.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" />
                <ButtonBar prefHeight="150.0" prefWidth="711.0">
                    <buttons>
                        <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#addcomponent" prefHeight="35.0" text="Add new component">
                            <graphic>
                                <ImageView fitHeight="30.0" fitWidth="75.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                                    <image>
                                        <Image url="@../IconsPack/white-plus-100.png" />
                                    </image>
                                </ImageView>
                            </graphic>
                        </Button>
                        <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#addstock" prefHeight="35.0" text="Add in stock">
                            <graphic>
                                <ImageView fitHeight="30.0" fitWidth="75.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                                    <image>
                                        <Image url="@../IconsPack/white-add-database-100.png" />
                                    </image>
                                </ImageView>
                            </graphic>
                        </Button>
                        <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#removestock" prefHeight="35.0" text="Remove from stock">
                            <graphic>
                                <ImageView fitHeight="30.0" fitWidth="75.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                                    <image>
                                        <Image url="@../IconsPack/white-remove-data-100.png" />
                                    </image>
                                </ImageView>
                            </graphic>
                        </Button>
                    </buttons>
                </ButtonBar>
            </children>
        </HBox>
    </top>
   <center>
      <Pane fx:id="mainPane" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
   </center>
</BorderPane>
```

**dashboardPane.fxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Text?>


<Pane style="-fx-background-color: #158790;">
   <children>
      <Text layoutY="18.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Dashboard" />
   </children>
</Pane>
```

Comment: If you want the [`Stage`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.graphics/javafx/stage/Stage.html) to expand and contract as needed, consider `sizeToScene()`.

Comment: What exactly is the issue?  Can you provide some images which demonstrate it?  Also, can you provide an example that doesn't use images and style sheets that aren't provided?

Comment: `nodeOrientation` is for switching between left to right (like English) and right to left (like Arabic) languages.  If you aren't doing that, don't use it.

Comment: You note that "I don't want to hardcode the size of each pane", yet in your example you have things like `<Pane fx:id="mainPane" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0"`.  If you don't want to hardcode the size of each pane (and not doing so is the recommended approach), then get rid of all pixel-based sizing constraints like this.  You can, instead, use layout pane specific hints, such as VGrow, HGrow, etc., on the layout panes if and when that is required.

Comment: A Pane isn't a managed layout pane like a VBox or HBox, it is built so the user can explicitly specify the layout.  If you want to have the layout managed, then use an appropriate layout pane.  From the [Pane](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/layout/Pane.html) doc: "It is the application's responsibility to position the children since the pane leaves the positions alone during layout".

Comment: See if the ideas [here](https://github.com/sedj601/RestaurantOrdersDuplicateFX) can help.

Answer (score 0):

you need add `fx:id=""` to you pane
`<Pane fx:id="myPane" style="-fx-background-color: #158790;">`

then try to

```java
AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(myPane, 0.0);
AnchorPane.setTopmAnchor(myPane, 0.0);
AnchorPane.setLeftmAnchor(myPane, 0.0);
AnchorPane.setRightmAnchor(myPane, 0.0);
```

do not forget

```java
@FXML
Pane mypane;
```

or (for fxml)

```java
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Text?>


<Pane AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" style="-fx-background-color: #158790;">
   <children>
      <Text layoutY="18.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Dashboard" />
   </children>
</Pane>
```